# CD box label designer

Tags: software-recommendation, printing, cd

Is there any good program for printing CD jewel case labels, which:

- automatically fetches the track titles from freedb or similar cdda database
- allows to customize layout (background color, element placement, size of the images).

On Windows there is CDRLabel (tried to run this using wine, but hangs during accessing the freedb).

I've already tried: `kover`, `disc-over`, `glabel` and `cd-circleprint`.

Comment: Have you tried Brasero?

Comment: @Roland, Brasero just burns the discs AFAIK. I think the poster is looking more for something that can actually make printable labels after the disc is burned.

Comment: @War Brasero can (it has a cover designer).

Comment: @Roland, I finally found it under Brasero's Tools menu...guess I learned something new.

Comment: @War I guess so.

Comment: @Roland Forgot to mention...you should probably post your Brasero suggestion as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Brasero for this by going to tools->cover editor.

[image]

Optionally you can install glabels 3.x from source (it's available on the [glabels home page](http://www.glabels.org/)), or try making something custom in the GIMP.

Unfortunately none of these pull in data from the CDs afaik. You can report this as a wishlist bug against brasero, however.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the automatic option of 'Read CD Tracks…' in [ronyasoft CD DVD label maker](https://www.ronyasoft.com/products/cd-dvd-label-maker/).

See example [Track reader dialog box screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h94eQ.jpg)